# Why is Wireshark not showing any TCP, UDP, DNS or HTTP traffic?

Tags: wireshark, sniffing, packet

I'm using Wireshark 4.0.2 on Kali 6.0.0 with an Alfa AWUS036ACS and in managed mode with promiscuous mode enabled I don't see any TCP, UDP, DNS or HTTP.

If I switch to monitor mode with promiscuous mode still enabled all I get is 802.11 protocol and when I try to decrypt using `wpa-pwd` it says invalid key format. I'm not seeing the eapol either.

I have checked and verified that the adapter and Wireshark are using the same channel/frequency. I have also rebooted a device and reconnected to wifi during a scan to see eapol but it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to sniff a Wifi network using a Wifi adapter. Are you sure your Wifi adapter is capable of running in promiscuous mode?

Comment: Yes I think it is. I also forgot to mention I was able to verify injection working with aireplay-ng

Comment: That Alfa dongle is a 1x1 (not MIMO) so it can't capture most modern Wi-Fi traffic, which is usually at least 2x2 MIMO nowadays.

Comment: I think I understand but is there anyway to still use it for practice even if I'm limited in its use? Also, can you recommend one that would work better for this? I was considering buying the alfa awus036acm