# Cannot see HTTP when using Wireshark on two different models of Alfa Wi-Fi adapters

Tags: wireshark, sniffing

I just upgraded my Wi-Fi adapter from Alfa AWUS036ACS to the Alfa AWUS036ACM and I can tell it's much better.

However, I am still not getting the desired results in Wireshark which leads me to believe I am missing something fundamental about the process.

I am using Wireshark 4.0.2 on Kali 6.0.0.

For example, even when capturing on the PC running Wireshark I am unable to decrypt because I get "invalid key format". I have tried to capture EAPoL from phone by starting Wireshark in monitor mode and then restarting the phone but no success. I only get 802.11 this way.

If run in managed mode, I now see TCP, UDP, DNS but still no HTTP. I'm sure that I must be missing something but can not figure out what it is.

I tried to go to YouTube on the machine running Wireshark as well as a phone while sniffing just to see if it comes up in Wireshark but I do not see it in either managed or monitor mode. I'm sure I'm probably missing something obvious but not sure what.

Comment: Please describe the issue in more detail - you're trying to capture http traffic from a phone on wifi? Maybe add a screenshot of the traffic you can see but not decrypt? Have you followed the steps here to add the pwd/psk to wireshark? https://wiki.wireshark.org/HowToDecrypt802.11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is wireshark behaving this way?](https://superuser.com/questions/1760359/why-is-wireshark-behaving-this-way)

Comment: When I try to add the pwd/psk it gives me "invalid key format" when I click the field to add the password/key.

Comment: @Lin what type of key is it? wep keys are entered in hex only for example, so only characters `0-9,a-f`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale It should be either wpa-pwd or wpa-psk. I have only tried wpa-pwd so far because I think it should work though I'm not 100% on that

Comment: @Lin are you adding the wpa-pwd with the SSID like `MyPassword:MySSID`? psk would be 64 hex characters. If you have something weird in your pwd or ssid, try and generate the psk using wireshark's tool (https://www.wireshark.org/tools/wpa-psk.html), and use that

Comment: @Cpt.Whale when I go into edit>preferences>protocols>IEEE 802.11 I click edit and than click "create new entry". Than I click to select wpa-pwd and finally I click the key field to enter the password and upon clicking this field it say "invalid key format".

Comment: @Lin The moment you click the field, **before** you enter the password, you get that error? Can you look at the file path in the bottom-right of that window and see if that file contains invalid entries?

Comment: @Spiff Yes I get the error after clicking the field but before actually typing anything. When I click the path in bottom right the file contains line 1 saying "This file is automatically generated, DO NOT MODIFY." and line 2 is blank.